# Connecting RDBMS using Embark

Tags: embark

Can someone please explain,  How can we configure SQL database for e.g. MySQL using Embark framework and How do we configure this in application.

Comment: It seems to me that this question may be a bit off-topic. Have you asked the question in Embark gitter? The questions on this stackexchange should be more focused specifically on Ethereum. I know Embark is Ethereum related, but the question is really about Embark, not Ethereum. Welcome, though, I see this is your first question.

Comment: @amit-kumar-kashyap please explain more your use case

Comment: Thanks. We want to make some financial transactions which we can store in the blockchain and can be verified later whenever required. Since blockchain is not suitable to store huge data and we also want to store all meta information of the transactions for e.g user name, address, phone number, bank account details other transaction details in SQL so that we can query and search by any keyword in the meta information.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing connecting Embark dapps to any type of database. Your best bet would be to treat connecting to a database as a separate application.